# Can we ask question by referring the equations, say, in an article in Wikipedia?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I was reading about "[Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula)" in Wikipedia, yet there is something I can't understand. So can I copy the link and say I did not understand this and this in that link?

It seems wrong because I don't remember seeing such questions but if it is ok, easier.

Comment: If you [google a bit](https://www.google.com/search?q=wikipedia+site:math.stackexchange.com), you will find several questions asking for clarification of some Wikipedia article. 
Examples: [Understanding isPrime function from Wikipedia](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1335310),
[Explanation of derivation made at wikipedia.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1347061) or [Is the Wikipedia article on the proof for Bertrand's Postulate correct?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1128560)

Comment: I asked to me this kind of  questions (for example, if I plot a graph of a function using a widget of Wolfram Alpha, can I do a copy paste in this site, in a post, of the image, is it right?). I don't know neither I don't ask your answer, I hope that the answers of the users can clarify to you.

Comment: I don't see why not. Reading Wikipedia can cause confusion in the first place, though. Just saying.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If it is at all possible you should make the question self-contained, that is you should reproduce the relevant content here (mentioning the source, and linking it for further context).

There may be cases where this is not possible, but often they will result in too broad or otherwise unsuitable questions.

Comment: This is especially relevant for a source like Wikipedia, where the text is likely to change and so the question may not make sense to readers coming back months later.

Answer (score 16):

This is closer to a comment than to an answer, but I will point out few details:

- It is good to mention the source of your question. (In this case, a Wikipedia article.) But since the Wikipedia articles change, it might be a good idea to add also link to the current revision. (If you click on "View History", you can see list of revisions. From there, you can also obtain a link to a particular revision, like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Poisson_summation_formula&oldid=680211788).)
- Usually,<sup>1</sup> it should be relatively easy to copy a formula from Wikipedia. This might browser-dependent, but probably already selecting the formula and trying to copy-paste will give you a format suitable to use here. But what should work reliably is viewing the source (by clicking on edit), finding the formula there and copying it. For example, in the article you mentioned you can find this: `\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \hat f\left(k\right)`. Exactly the same syntax works here: $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \hat f\left(k\right).$$

---

<sup>1</sup>For simple and inline formulas, you will often find some combination of HTML and Wikipedia syntax, like here: `L<sup>1</sup>('''R''')`. So this only works for formulas enclosed in `<math>...</math>`.